# Bulk insert error "Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, data-migration

I'm trying to do bulk insert from csv file with the following script:

```
BULK INSERT x.tableName
FROM 'PATH OF FILE'
WITH (
      FIRSTROW = 2,
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
      ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\SchoolsErrorRows.csv',
      TABLOCK    )
```

My issue is that I have a column in the database of type `Datetime2` and the format of the column in the csv file like this : 2020-12-01 20:15:00 +0300

I got this error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (Date).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Probably not the fix you were looking for, but have you considered opening the file with notepad++ and using regex to format. Alternatively you could insert it into a staging table and have the date insert as a varchar, then modify it and update another column with the datetime type. Once finished just drop the string column, or just ignore it when inserting into the real table.

Comment: I figure out another way which it removing +0300 part and it worked without errors